# Como comparar a diferença entre duas datas em Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Preciso comparar 2 datas para saber se a data de vencimento é **Maior** que a data atual, se for **Menor** ele retorna um erro, segue o código que eu fiz e não deu certo.

```pascal
 var
 Data_Atual: String;
 Data_vencimento: String;
 begin
 Data_Atual := DateToSTr(Date);
 Data_Vencimento := '20/02/2014';
 if (Data_Vencimento < Data_Atual);
 showmessage('A Data de Vencimento é menor que a data atual');
 end;
```

O que eu fiz de errado ?

Comment: Use o TYPE DATE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Só um cuidado a tomar: se usar StrToDate('20/02/2014') e a máquina do usuário estiver com padrão de datas em inglês, vai dar erro.

Sempre que comparar datas no formato string, você deve inverter a formatação. Deve ficar ano / mes / dia. OK?

Exemplo de código:

```
var
   Data_Atual: string;
   Data_vencimento: string;
 begin
   Data_Atual := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', Date);
   Data_Vencimento := '2014/02/20';
   if (Data_Vencimento < Data_Atual) then
     ShowMessage('A Data de Vencimento é menor que a data atual');
 end;
```

Comment: deu certo perfeitamente....obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Como citado na [**resposta do Heber**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17342/6454) você pode comparar datas através dos [operadores](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/expressions_xml.html) `>` e `<` além de `=` para verificar se coincidem.

```pascal
Var
 DataAtual, DataVencimento: String;
Begin
 DataAtual := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', Date);
 DataVencimento := '20/02/2014';

 If (DataVencimento = DataAtual) then
   ShowMessage('A Data atual coincide com a Data de Vencimento!')

 Else If (DataVencimento > DataAtual) then
   ShowMessage('A Data Atual é superior a Data de Vencimento!')

 Else If DataVencimento < DataAtual then
   ShowMessage('A Data Atual é inferior a Data de Vencimento!')
End;
```

Se preferir, há também uma biblioteca que disponibiliza algumas funções que te permitem trabalhar com datas/horas de um modo mais preciso, a [`DateUtils`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17342/6454).

### Exemplos

Para comparar a diferença entre duas datas, utilize a função [`CompareDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.DateUtils.CompareDate):

```pascal
Var
 DataAtual, DataVencimento: TDate;
 Value: Integer;
Begin
 DataAtual := StrToDate(FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', Now));
 DataVencimento := StrToDate('20/02/2014');

 Value := CompareDate(DataAtual, DataVencimento);
 If Value = 0 then
    MessageDlg('A Data Atual coincide com a Data de Vencimento!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0)
 Else If Value = 1 then
    MessageDlg('A Data Atual é superior a Data de Vencimento!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0)
 Else
    MessageDlg('A Data Atual é inferior a Data de Vencimento!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
End;
```

Para saber a diferença de dias entre duas datas utilize a função [`DaysBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.DateUtils.DaysBetween):

```pascal
Var
DataAtual, DataVencimento: TDate;
Diff: String;
Begin
 DataAtual := StrToDate(FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', Now));
 DataVencimento := StrToDate('20/02/2014');
 Diff := FloatToStr(DaysBetween(DataAtual, DataVencimento));

 MessageDlg(Format('A diferença entre %s e %s é de %s dias', 
       [DateToStr(DataAtual), DateToStr(DataVencimento), Diff]), 
       mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
End;
```

Para saber a diferença de semanas entre duas datas utilize a função [`WeeksBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.DateUtils.WeeksBetween):

```pascal
Var
DataAtual, DataVencimento: TDate;
Diff: String;
Begin
 DataAtual := StrToDate(FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', Now));
 DataVencimento := StrToDate('20/02/2014');
 Diff := FloatToStr(WeeksBetween(DataAtual, DataVencimento));

 MessageDlg(Format('A diferença entre %s e %s é de %s semanas', 
       [DateToStr(DataAtual), DateToStr(DataVencimento), Diff]), 
       mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
End;
```

Para saber a diferença de meses entre datas use a função [`MonthsBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.DateUtils.MonthsBetween), para anos use [`YearsBetween`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.DateUtils.YearsBetween).

**Relacionado**: [Cálculo de datas no firebird](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42729/6454)

Comment: mesmo colocando o DateUtils no USES, quando declarei a variável como TDATE, ele deu erro, dizendo que o TDATE não foi definido. Alguma ideia ?

Comment: quando dou um showmessage no Data_Atual, ele mostra um monte de código doido, e não a data de hoje...

Comment: quero mostrar a data de hoje, não tem como eu comparar datas usando variável STRING para as datas igual eu fiz no código acima ? E não usando TDateTime ?

Comment: se você fizer dessa forma: DATA_ATUAL := StrToDate(DateToStr(Now)); ele não mostra a data se a variável for TDATETIME como você recomendou. Testa ai pra você ver.

Answer (score 1):

Use a função `decodeDate()`.

Nela, você passa 4 parametros:

- O primeiro é a data;
- No segundo você passa uma variável para onde a função extrairá o ANO da data;
- No terceiro você passa uma variável para onde a função extrairá o MES da data;
- No quarto você passa uma variável para onde a função extrairá o DIA da data.

No seu caso, você chama esse procedimento duas vezes e subtrai o valor dos dois dias. Mais ou menos asim:

```pascal
    var
    DataInicial, DataFinal : TDateTime;
    AnoInicial, AnoFinal, MesInicial, MesFinal, DiaInicial, DiaFinal : Word;
    DiferencaEntreDias : Integer;

    Begin

      decodeDate(DateFinal, AnoFinal, MesFinal, DiaFinal);
      decodeDate(DataInicial, AnoInicial, MesInicial, DiaInicial);

      DiferencaEntreDias := DiaFinal - DiaInicial;

    end;
```

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que esse **`coigo{`** significa *Código:* e não faz parte da linguagem de programação, mas não quis alterar nem remover.

Comment: não, não faz parte... somente erro...rsrrsrsr

Comment: Pois então? Oxi! Você é livre pra **[edit]** seus posts e melhorá-los... :P