# Cálculo de datas no firebird

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, firebird

Estou criado um relatório para demonstrar o período de afastamento dos funcionários, para isso preciso calcular os dias, meses e anos que o mesmo ficou afastado, e estou tendo um problema, no Firebird uso algo como `datediff(day,dtini,dtfim)`, o problema é que se passada uma período como 02/02/2014 e 02/02/2014 diz que houve 0 dias de afastamento, um problema é que o `datediff` me retorna um dia a menos.

Outro problema é que não conheço função no Firebird que me retorne períodos em dias, meses e anos, já considerando o número de dias de cada mês, deixando uma margem de erro no cálculo já que estou fazendo esse cálculo de forma aproximada.

Comment: `2-2==0`, não é? Para resolver seu problema não é só somar `1` ao resultado do datediff? E o que você quer dizer com margem de erro? Como você quer usar margem de erro em uma conta de subtração?

Comment: 01/12/2014 Á 30/01/2015 - o meu resultado retorna 2 meses e 1 dia entende! somando +1.não quero usar margem de erro, quero tirar a margem, como acima `2-2==0 +1 =1` só que em alguns casos da uma dia a mais se somar +1

Comment: São dois meses de 31 dias. Uma data menos a outra dá 60 dias de diferença. Como você chegou no valor de `2 meses`, o próprio firebird faz essa conversão para você ou você apenas dividiu por 30 para calcular quantos meses são?

Comment: exemplificando novamente o meu problema, preciso calcular de uma maneira mais "dinâmica", pois quando passa de um mês, divido o valor por 30, dando valores errados, pois alguns meses tem 31 dias, já tentei fazer um `if` verificando se o mês inicial tem 31 dias, mas o cálculo fica errado.

Comment: Agora entendi o que quis dizer com a margem de erro. É que acho que tinha um erro de digitação na sua pergunta, dá uma olhada no que eu modifiquei. A propósito, você está trabalhando com alguma linguagem de programação em conjunto? Pois pode fazer essa conta da diferença dos dias já considerando os números de dias de cada mês através da própria linguagem, ao invés de usar o banco para isso.

Comment: @Balrog, fiz alguns testes aqui e não há nada de estranho com a função `datadiff`, o que parece estar estranho é sua logica, não sei como você fez isso: "01/12/2014 Á 30/01/2015 - o meu resultado retorna 2 meses e 1 dia entende", pois isso `select datediff (day, date '1-Dec-2014', date '30-Jan-2015') from rdb$database`, retorna 60 dias, então está correto, o seu problema parecer ser converter os dias em anos, meses e dias, certo?

Comment: Estou trabalhando com Delhpi 7, e Firebird, mas tenho o seguinte, é um relatório, os dados estão todos no Firebird, sim o problema é na conversão. o exemplo acima e um, mas pode ter períodos longos que precisarei calcular.

Comment: @Balrog Você tem a data de início do afastamento e a dataFim do afastamento e quer retornar via query quantos dias afastados o indivíduo ficou, certo? Vão ser considerados meses de 30 dias ou a contagem em dias mesmo?

Comment: @Caputo Vão ser considerados meses, quando os dias são maiores que 30 estou dividindo por 30, preciso mostrar o período que o indivíduo ficou afastado como: 1 Ano 2 Meses e 25 dias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Delphi não possui função nativa que retorne a diferença de datas "humanizada" como disse o @Omni no chat, mas você pode utilizar a DateUtils do delphi para gerar essa informação:

*Obs: No seu caso como de um dia até ele mesmo é um dia de afastamento, terá de somar 1 a data final*

```
function TForm1.PeriodoExtenso(const DataInicial, DataFinal: TDate): string;
var
  Anos, Meses, Dias: Integer;
  DataAjustada: TDateTime;
  Periodo: string;
begin
  Periodo := EmptyStr; //Variaveis locais no delphi não são inicializadas por padrao

  Anos := YearsBetween(DataInicial, DataFinal);
  DataAjustada := IncYear(DataInicial, Anos);
  Meses := MonthsBetween(DataAjustada, DataFinal);
  DataAjustada := IncMonth(DataAjustada, Meses);
  Dias := DaysBetween(DataAjustada, DataFinal);

  if Anos > 0 then
    Periodo := Format('%d anos', [Anos]);

  if Meses > 0 then
  begin
    if Periodo <> EmptyStr then
      Periodo := Periodo + ' e ';

    Periodo := Format('%s%d meses', [Periodo, Meses]);
  end;

  if Dias > 0 then
  begin
    if Periodo <> EmptyStr then
      Periodo := Periodo + ' e ';

    Periodo := Format('%s%d dias', [Periodo, dias]);
  end;

  Result := Periodo;
end;
```

Comment: Obrigado mas é mais ou menos isso que faço hoje, até um pouco mais "aprimorado" pois se para para olhar o `DaysBetween` pode retornar mais que 30 dias, no meu caso, irei mostrar no relatório, 1 ano e 2 meses e 3 dias - 427 dias,

Comment: @Balrog posso te passar como fazer o mesmo via SQL caso tenha interesse, mas é razoavelmente complexo, ou até mesmo via storedProcedure

Comment: Claro que gostaria que me passasse, se puder postar caso não for muito extenso.

Comment: @Balrog, tenho de entregar uma demanda urgente aqui, assim q liberar um pouco monto a lógica dela e te passo na resposta mesmo. Qual versao do firebird?

Comment: Versão 2.5, aqui estou meio ocupado também. por isso a demora para te responder. Não tem muita pressa.